# Could not load my own modules in ghci haskell

Tags: haskell, importerror, ghci

i am trying to load a module called Point.hs into a file called Circle.hs by this way:

```
module Figures.Circle 
( Circle(..)
  , getArea
  , getPerimeter
) where

import qualified Figures.Point as P
```

here is my Point.hs file:

```
 module Figures.Point  
( Point(..)  
) where
```

this is my directory´s tree:

- Figures/

  - Point.hs
  - Circle.hs

and this is what ghci´s error says:

```
Circle.hs:7:1: error:
    Could not find module `Figures.Point'
    Locations searched:
      Figures\Point.hs
      Figures\Point.lhs
      Figures\Point.hsig
      Figures\Point.lhsig
  |
7 | import qualified Figures.Point as P
```

I follow this [guide](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#making-our-own-modules).

Comment: What does `:show paths` say? Is the current working directory printed there the one that contains `Figures`?

Comment: (See also: [Why can't ghci find the hs file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68399377/791604).)

Comment: i run the :show paths and show me this `C:\Figures
module import search paths:
  .`

Comment: Okay. You should start ghci from `C:\ `, not from `C:\\Figures` (as suggested in the current answer from Noughtmare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error if I call `ghci` from within the `Figures` directory, that can be avoided by calling `ghci` from the parent directory, so `ghci Figures\Circle.hs`.